# Get file name from absolute path in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, path, fs

How can I get the file name from an absolute path in Nodejs?

e.g. `"foo.txt"` from `"/var/www/foo.txt"`

I know it works with a string operation, like `fullpath.replace(/.+\//, '')`,
but I want to know is there an explicit way, like `file.getName()` in Java?

Answer (score 826, accepted):

Use the `basename` method of the `path` module:

```
path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html')
// returns
'quux.html'
```

[Here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) is the documentation the above example is taken from..

Comment: If you also want to remove the extension: `path.basename(fpath, path.extname(fpath))`

Answer (score 77):

To get the file name portion of the file name, the basename method is used:

```
var path = require("path");
var fileName = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe";
var file = path.basename(fileName);

console.log(file); // 'python.exe'
```

If you want the file name without the extension, you can pass the extension variable (containing the extension name) to the basename method telling Node to return only the name without the extension:

```
var path = require("path");
var fileName = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe";
var extension = path.extname(fileName);
var file = path.basename(fileName,extension);

console.log(file); // 'python'
```

Comment: If you want the file name without the extension, I recommend use: `path.parse(fileName).name`

Answer (score 47):

```
var path = require("path");

var filepath = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe";

var name = path.parse(filepath).name;
console.log("name:", name); // Output: python

var base = path.parse(filepath).base;
console.log("base:", base); // Output: python.exe

var ext = path.parse(filepath).ext;
console.log("ext:", ext); // Output: .exe

var dir = path.parse(filepath).dir;
console.log("dir:", dir); // Output: C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2

var root = path.parse(filepath).root;
console.log("root:", root); // Output: C:\
```

OR

```
const path = require("path");
const filepath = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2\\python.exe";

const { name, base, ext, dir, root } = path.parse(filepath);

console.log(`Name: ${name}\nBase: ${base}\nExtension: ${ext}\nDirectory: ${dir}\nRoot: ${root}`);
```

Comment: you forget `root` and `dir`

Answer (score 16):

For those interested in removing extension from filename, you can use
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext

```
path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html', '.html');
```

Comment: Also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811541/nodejs-get-file-name-from-absolute-path/19811573#comment74745217_19811573) is useful

Answer (score 5):

If you already know that the path separator is `/` (i.e. you are writing for a specific platform/environment), as implied by the example in your question, you could keep it simple and split the string by separator:

```
'/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html'.split('/').pop()
```

That would be [faster](https://jsperf.com/basename-from-path/1) (and cleaner imo) than replacing by regular expression.

Again: Only do this if you're writing for a specific environment, otherwise use the `path` module, as paths are surprisingly complex. Windows, for instance, supports `/` in many cases but [not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx) for e.g. the `\\?\?` style prefixes used for shared network folders and the like. On Windows the above method is doomed to fail, sooner or later.

Comment: Windows have \ as folder separator

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Yes, that's why I write “If you already know that the path separator is /”... :)

Comment: it's not clear what you meant with this statement. This produces platform dependent code that will silently fail on on other platforms

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic Yes, it does indeed. Always use the methods of the path module if you are not writing for a specific platform.

Comment: windows actually accepts both / and \ as folder seperators & you can even mix it up

Comment: @RozzA Not always, I'm afraid: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

Answer (score 4):

`path` is a `nodeJS module` meaning you don't have to install any package for using its properties.

```
import path from 'path'
const dir_name = path.basename('/Users/Project_naptha/demo_path.js')
console.log(dir_name)

// returns
demo_path.js
```

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js, you can get the file name from an absolute path using the path module. Specifically, you can use the path.basename() function to extract the file name from a given path.

sample code:

```
const path = require('path');

const absolutePath = '/var/www/foo.txt';
const fileName = path.basename(absolutePath);

console.log(fileName); // Output: foo.txt
```

The path.basename() function will automatically extract the file name from the given path

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, __filename.split(/\|//).pop() returns just the file name from the absolute file path on any OS platform.
Why need to care about remembering/importing an API while this regex approach also letting us recollect our regex skills.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

So Nodejs comes with the default global variable called  `'__fileName'` that holds the current file being executed
My advice is to pass the __fileName to a service from any file , so that the retrieval of the fileName is made dynamic

Below, I make use of the fileName string and then split it based on the `path.sep`. Note path.sep avoids issues with posix file seperators and windows file seperators (issues with  '/' and '\'). It is much cleaner. Getting the substring and getting only the last seperated name and subtracting it with the actulal length by 3 speaks for itself.

You can write a service like this (Note this is in typescript , but you can very well write it in js )

```
export class AppLoggingConstants {

    constructor(){

    }
      // Here make sure the fileName param is actually '__fileName'
    getDefaultMedata(fileName: string, methodName: string) {
        const appName = APP_NAME;
        const actualFileName = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(path.sep)+1, fileName.length - 3);
        //const actualFileName = fileName;
     return appName+ ' -- '+actualFileName;
    }


}

export const AppLoggingConstantsInstance = new AppLoggingConstants();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, you can use the built-in path module to get this. You can just utilize the path.basename() method, it extracts the last portion of a path.

check the below how you can get the file name from an absolute path:

```
const path = require('path');

const absolutePath = '/var/www/mytext.txt';
const fileName = path.basename(absolutePath);

console.log(fileName); // Output will be "mytext.txt" in this case
```

The above code will extract the file name (mytext.txt) from the absolute path (/var/www/mytext.txt) using path.basename(). Thanks