# Get directory from a file path or url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the directory location of a file, and I'm not sure how to get it. I can't seem to find a module that allows me to do this.

So for example say I have this string:

```
/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html
```

how can I get this:

```
/this/is/a/path/to/a
```

I know I can use something like this:

```
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") - 1);
```

But I am not sure if that is as good of a method as something that might be built in to node.

I have also tried:

```
var info = url.parse(full_path);
console.log(info);
```

and the result doesn't return what I am looking for, that gets the full path including the filename.

So, is there something built into node that can do this and do it well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811541/nodejs-get-file-name-from-absolute-path

Comment: that is the opposite of what I want. I want the path not the filename

Comment: if you looked at the answer and clicked on the documentation, the function directly above the one they linked is what you were looking for

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p) module of node.js:

```
path.dirname('/this/is/a/path/to/a/file');
```

returns

```
'/this/is/a/path/to/a'
```

Comment: It actually returns `/this/is/a/path/to/a`, without the last `/`

Comment: path.dirname('/this/is/a/path/to/a/directory/') returns '/this/is/a/path/to/a' when that is definitely a full directory. This function has a bug. Note:  A path can be either a directory, a file by itself, or a directory + file.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce I do not believe this is a bug.  It mirrors the behavior of the UNIX dirname command.  See https://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Misconceptions - documented. Bash-complete seems to auto-completes a directory with a ending / which is where my confusion stems from. I am unsure how to push this for review on the manpages.

Answer (score 26):

Using plain JS, this will work:

```
var e = '/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html'
e.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/")  //split to array & remove last element

//result: '/this/is/a/path/to/a'
```

**OR...** if you prefer a one liner (using regex):

```
"/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html".replace(/(.*?)[^/]*\..*$/,'$1')

//result: '/this/is/a/path/to/a/'
```

**OR...** finally, the good old fashioned (and faster):

```
var e = '/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html'
e.substr(0, e.lastIndexOf("/"))

//result: '/this/is/a/path/to/a'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for `path.dirname`

Answer (score 2):

```
filepath.split("/").slice(0,-1).join("/"); // get dir of filepath
```

1. split string into array delimited by "/"
2. drop the last element of the array (which would be the file name + extension)
3. join the array w/ "/" to generate the directory path

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed to convert s3 bucket paths!

Comment: p.split("/").slice(0, -2).join("/"); - if your path ends with a "/"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `dirname` function of the `path` module: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p

```
path.dirname('/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html')
// returns
'/this/is/a/path/to/a'
```

Answer (score -1):

For plain JavaScript, this will work:

```
function getDirName(e)
{
     if(e === null) return '/';

     if(e.indexOf("/") !== -1)
     {
         e = e.split('/')            //break the string into an array
         e.pop()                     //remove its last element
         e= e.join('/')              //join the array back into a string
         if(e === '')
              return '/';
         return e;
     }

     return "/";
}


var e = '/this/is/a/path/to/a/file.html'
var e = 'file.html'
var e = '/file.html'
getDirName(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get dirname with just with **__dirname**.

Comment: That is the directory of the current file. That won't work when getting the value of any path.