# Sequelize model loading in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently studying using NodeJS, Express, PostgreSQL and Sequelize on Scotch.io then I came across this:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
var db        = {};

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) & (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

I am seeking an explanation of this code in plain terms. What exactly is happening here?

I do understand the part where we default to `development` if Node environment is not set but I need clarification of the file reading part i.e where `fs` begins.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the explanation. Much clearer now. Just one more thing, what is this line for: 

var basename  = path.basename(module.filename);?

Comment: I believe it just strips the filename from its path. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811541/nodejs-get-file-name-from-absolute-path for a discussion on it if you'd like.

Ie I believe the return is `index.js` (assuming the file is called index.js).

Comment: Thank you so much man! Your response was really helpful.

Comment: That's great, happy to help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, note that this code is generated by `sequelize-cli` by running `sequelize init` and is placed in a file called `index.js` located in a `models/` folder.

**1. The Configuration Environment**

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

This is helpful for when in production. As an example, I'll show you my code:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    username: '<username name>',
    password: 'test',
    database: '<db name>',
    host: 'localhost'
  },
  production: {
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: true
    },
    protocol: 'postgres',
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL'
  }
}
```

Heroku sets a process variable `DATABASE_URL` that I simply point to. The username, password etc are obtained from this, rather than listing them explicitly in `config.js`, as development credentials are.

**2. Importing/Reading Models**

```
fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) & (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
```

`fs.readdirSync` synchronously reads the directory given in its argument. In this case, it's `__dirname`, which is the directory that this index.js file is in. Here, the models you defined in `models/` directory are pulled in. Notice that the filter function is just making sure that:

- There are files to read
- It excludes this file (ie not index.js)
- They end in '.js'

Each model file is then keyed into the exports Object with the line `db[model.name] = model;`

**3. Associating Each Model**

```
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Lastly, once we have obtained all of the model files (from the previous read), we run each model's `associate` function, if it exists. This is a method that's defined in each model file as follows:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Model1 = sequelize.define('Model1',
    { ... })

  // Class Method
  Model1.associate = function (models) {
    Model1.belongsTo(models.Model2)
  }
  return Model1
}
```

**4. Exported Use**

Both an instance of your sequelize database (`sequelize`) and an instance of the `Sequelize` library are exported.

In this manner we can now do the following:

assume a directory structure of

- models/

  - index.js
  - model1.js
  - model2.js

`require('./models').Model1 // access to your models`

This is how you'll import and use your models, rather than directly through their definition files. This ensures they're synced and associated properly.

Likewise we have access to sequelize:

```
require('./models')
  .sequelize.sync({ force: true }) // access to your sequelize db
```

Comment: is your `config.json` is in `.gitignore` ?

Comment: @keshavAggarwal No - it's safe to checkin `.config.json`. If you don't want the development credentials exposed, then use environment variables. A common package used is [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). **You *should* ignore `.env` files.**

Answer (score 1):

In plain terms, this is importing all the `.js` files from the same directory as this file. This is done through `sequelize['import']` method.

Moreover it is assumed that all these files contain sequelize models, as the return value from the import is mapped on dictionary named `db`.

```
db[model.name] = model
```

Once all the files are imported and models are mapped to `db`, a loop is run to call `associate` on each model, only if that model contains associate method. Usually associate method is used to define all the associations between the models i.e. `hasMany`, `hasOne`, `belongsTo` etc.

Comment: Great! Thank you.