# Finding the directory portion of a String containing a file name in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Processing a bunch of files using Node and I need to separate the file name from the directory.  Does node have a simple way to do this without additional dependencies?  I could use an NPM package like [Filename Regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filename-regex), but thought I'd check if there something available out of the box?

So for example suppose we have `src/main/css/file.css`.  Hoping something like this is possible:

```
 const fs = require('fs');
 const path = fs.filePath(String pathAndFileName);  //path = src/main/css
 const file = fs.fileName(String pathAndFileName);  //file = file.css
```

Comment: Sorry but it is a bit unclear to me what you're asking. You want the file names in a directory or what ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs get file name from absolute path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811541/nodejs-get-file-name-from-absolute-path)

Comment: All those functions are in path: https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The utilities for manipulating file paths are in the path module.
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

```
 const {dirname, basename}  = require('path');

 const path = dirname(String pathAndFileName);
 const file = basename(String pathAndFileName);
```