# Webpack import order creating shadowing between code in a file and code in a folder

Tags: webpack, import, shadowing

We have on occasion the situation where we'll have:

`import { foo, bar } from '../../services/blaService';`

where we have both the file `blaService.ts` and the folder `blaService/index.ts`.

Webpack loads the file first and discards the code in the folder which is expected behaviour.

Could we have a way to guard against this by for instance throwing an error when such a code shadowing scenario occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR;

Here would be a way to solve it:

#### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const DetectShadowingPlugin = {
  apply (resolver) {
    const beforeResolved = resolver.getHook('before-resolved');

    // `cb`- refers to the next `tap` function in the chain
    beforeResolved.tapAsync('DetectShadowingPlugin', (req, ctx, cb) => {
      // To inspect the hook's chain until this moment, see `ctx.stack`(from top to bottom)
      // console.log(ctx);
      
      // The `path` will give us the full path for the file we're looking for
      const { path: filePath } = req;
      
      const ext = path.extname(filePath);
      if (ext !== '.js') {
        // Continuing the process
        return cb();
      }

      const fileName = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath)); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/19811573/9632621
      const possibleDirectoryPath = path.resolve(filePath, '..', fileName);
      fs.access(possibleDirectoryPath, err => {
        if (!err) {
          const message = `Apart from the file ${filePath}, there is also a directory ${possibleDirectoryPath}`;
          cb(new Error(message));
          
          return;
        }

        cb();
      });
    });
  },
};

/**
 * @type {import("webpack/types").Configuration}
 */
const config = {
  /* ... */

  resolve: {
    plugins: [DetectShadowingPlugin]
  },
};

module.exports = config;
```

Result:

[image: result]

The file structure is as follows:

```
├── deps
│   ├── foo
│   │   └── index.js
│   └── foo.js
├── dist
│   └── main.js
├── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

and `foo` is imported like this:

```js
import defaultFooFn from './deps/foo';
```

If you want to try out the above example, you can check out [this Github repo](https://github.com/Andrei0872/understanding-webpack/tree/master/examples/import-order). I will add the set-up details in the repo's readme later(surely.. later :D), but until then, here are the steps:

- git clone --recurse-submodules
- cd webpack

  - yarn
  - yarn link
- cd ..
- yarn link webpack
- yarn understand - also check `package.json`'s scripts for more information about it

---

### Explanation

webpack uses a `resolver` for finding the location of the files. I see this *discovery process* as a collection of branch ramifications. Sort of like git branches. It has a starting point and based on some conditions, it chooses the paths to take until it reaches and endpoint.

If you copied the repo I linked in the previous section, you should see the webpack repo, in the `webpack` folder. If you want to better visualize these *ramifications* of choices, you can open the `webpack/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/ResolverFactory.js` file. You don't have to understand what's going on, but just notice the connections between the steps:

[image: ResolverFactory]

as you can see, `parsed-resolve` appears as an argument both on the first position and on the last position. You can also see that it's using all kinds of plugins, but they have a thing in common: generally, the first string is the **source** and the last string is the **target**. I mentioned earlier that this process can be seen as a ramification of branches. Well, these branches are composed of nodes(intuitively speaking), where a node is technically called a hook.

The starting point is the `resolve` hook(from the for loop). The next node after it is `parsed-resolve`(it is the `resolve` hook's **target**). The `parsed-resolve` hook's target is `described-resolve` hook. And so forth.

Now, there is an important thing to mention. As you might have noticed, the `described-resolve` hook is used multiple times as a **source**. Every time this happens, a new step(technically called `tap`) is added. When moving from one node to another, these steps are used. From one step you can go another route if that plugin(a step is added by a plugin) decides so(this can be the result of certain conditions being fulfilled in a plugin).

So, if you have something like this:

```js
plugins.push(new Plugin1("described-resolve", "another-target-1"));
plugins.push(new Plugin2("described-resolve", "another-target-1"));
plugins.push(new Plugin3("described-resolve", "another-target-2"));
```

From `described-resolve` you can go to `another-target-1` from 2 steps(so there are 2 ways to arrive to it). If one condition is not met in a plugin, it goes to the next condition until the plugin's condition is met. If `another-target-1` has not been chosen at all, then maybe `Plugin3`'s condition will lead the way to `another-target-2`.

So, this this the logic behind this process, as far as my perspective is concerned. Somewhere in this process, there is a hook(or a node, if we were to stick to the initial analogy) which is invoked after the **file has been successfully found**. This is the `resolved` hook, which is also represents the last part of the process.
If we reached the point, we know for sure that a file exists. What we could do now is to check whether a folder with the same name exists. And this is what this custom plugin is doing:

```js
const DetectShadowingPlugin = {
  apply (resolver) {
    const beforeResolved = resolver.getHook('before-resolved');

    beforeResolved.tapAsync('DetectShadowingPlugin', (req, ctx, cb) => {
      const { path: filePath } = req;
      
      const ext = path.extname(filePath);
      if (ext !== '.js') {
        return cb();
      }

      const possibleDirectoryPath = path.resolve(filePath, '..', fileName);
      fs.access(possibleDirectoryPath, err => {
        if (!err) {
          const message = `Apart from the file ${filePath}, there is also a directory ${possibleDirectoryPath}`;
          cb(new Error(message));
          
          return;
        }

        cb();
      });
    });
  },
};
```

There is an interesting implementation detail here, which is `before-resolved`. Remember that each hook, in order to determine its new target, it has to go through some conditions which are defined by plugins which use the same source. We're doing a similar thing here, with the exception that we're telling webpack to run our custom condition **first**. We could say that it adds some priority to it. If we wanted to run this among the last conditions, we'd replace `before` with `after`.

---

### Why it chooses the `requestName.js` path first instead of `requestName/index.js`

This is due to the order in which the built-in plugins are added. If you scroll down in `ResolverFactory` a bit, you should arrive at these lines:

```js
// The `requestName.js` will be chosen first!
plugins.push(
    new ConditionalPlugin(
        "described-relative",
        { directory: false },
        null,
        true,
        "raw-file"
    )
);

// If a successful path was found, there is no way of turning back.
// So if the above way is alright, this plugin's condition won't be invoked.
plugins.push(
    new ConditionalPlugin(
        "described-relative",
        { fullySpecified: false },
        "as directory",
        true,
        "directory"
    )
);
```

You can test it out by commenting out the `raw-file` plugin from above:

[image]

then, according to the repo, you should see something like that, indicating that had been chosen:

[image]

You can also place breakpoints wherever in that working tree and then press `F5` to inspect the execution of the program. Everything is in the `launch.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly thorough answer and for confirming my intuition that this could be caught by a webpack plugin.