# how can i match strings, if one of them are not complete equal?

Tags: javascript

i have two arrays and i want to verify to synchronic both, if in both existe the same name that should be stored in the array and the others no

for example: i need all the objects with name `rea.jpg` but in my array i have like this `['dsjajdsj...h2/rea.jpg']`
this is the materials

```
[{name: 'hgb.jpg' }, { name: 'rea.jpg'}, {  name: 'ca.png' }]
```

*the file extension is always the end of the string*

i want to verify if exist an object in the names's array

```js
const names = ['h2/rea.jpg']
const materials = [{
  name: 'hgb.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'rea.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'ca.png'
}]
const res = materials.filter(x => names.includes(x.name))
console.log('RES', res)
```

expected result shoud be  `[ {name: 'rea.jpg'}]`

Comment: Your `names` array has fully-qualified filenames (with paths) and I'm assuming you don't want to compare the path component, just the filename, so why not create a second array that has just the filenames from `names`? Then your filter code will work.

Comment: @jarmod How can I create that list of names without making any mistakes with this character / ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811541/nodejs-get-file-name-from-absolute-path/55311046

Comment: @jarmod i wont like to install a library or unless its too necesary?

Comment: @jarmod the ProGu's answer could work in all of cases?

Comment: The 'path' library is part of Node.js (assuming this is Node.js).

Comment: @jarmod oh i see, can you create your answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Node.js, you can use the `path` library to convert the fully-qualified pathnames to simple filenames, then do your includes test. For example:

```
const path = require('path');

const pathnames = ['h2/rea.jpg'];
const filenames = pathnames.map((x) => path.basename(x));

const materials = [
  {
    name: 'hgb.jpg',
  },
  {
    name: 'rea.jpg',
  },
  {
    name: 'ca.png',
  },
];

const res = materials.filter((x) => filenames.includes(x.name));
console.log('RES', res);
// RES [ { name: 'rea.jpg' } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#some` to pass in a custom compare function.

```js
const names = ['h2/rea.jpg']
const materials = [{
  name: 'hgb.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'rea.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'ca.png'
}]
const res = materials.filter(x => names.some(y => y.endsWith('/' + x.name)))
console.log('RES', res)
```

Comment: Will incorrectly match `law/mens-rea.jpg` etc.

Comment: revised to add leading /

Comment: The updated code will be OK if the `names` array elements *always* include a path.

Comment: original question said so

Comment: if names and materials are not in fixed pattern, it ends with no solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
const names = ['h2/rea.jpg']
const materials = [{
  name: 'hgb.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'rea.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'ca.png'
}]
const res = materials.filter(x => {
    const ni = names.filter(ni => ni.includes(x.name))
    return ni.length > 0
})
console.log(res)
```

But if names is long and you don't want to iterate over it on every element of materials follow the other suggestion and transform names to only include the filename.

```
const fnames = names.map(ni => ni.split('/')[ni.split('/').length-1])
const res = materials.filter(x => names.includes(x.name))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` inside of the filter to acheive this (note, this will run in O(n^2)).

```js
const names = ['h2/rea.jpg']
const materials = [{
  name: 'hgb.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'rea.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'ca.png'
}]
const res = materials.filter(x => names.some(y => y.endsWith('/' + x.name)))

console.log('RES', res)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like it oldscool, then with two loops and Regex.

```js
const names = ['h2/rea.jpg']
const materials = [{
    name: 'hgb.jpg'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'rea.jpg'
  }, 
  {
    name: 'ca.png'
  }]

  const res = [];

materials.forEach((x) => {
    let search = x.name    
    let reg = new RegExp(search, 'g');
    let match = '';
    names.forEach((n) => {
      match = n.match(reg);
    })
    if(match) {
      res.push(x)
    }  
})

console.log('RES', res)
```